# Get the data items of a Google Charts histogram bar or range of the bar

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart, histogram, selection, google-barchart

I'm trying to create an interactive histogram chart using Google Chart.
My code for generating the histogram can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shakedk/pvob8smd/2/).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['pt_network_seg_id','speed'],
['9','32'],
['10','22'],
['13','23'],
['14','18'],
['15','34'],
['17','22'],
['18','30'],
['19','20'],
['20','33'],
['21','26'],
['22','33'],
['23','21'],
['24','19'],
['25','41'],
['26','23'],
['27','16'],
['28','39'],
['29','15'],
['30','25'],
['31','26'],
['32','29'],
['40','31'],
['41','9'],
['42','27'],
['44','25'],
['45','10'],
['46','25'],
['47','24'],
['48','20'],
['49','20'],
['50','25'],
['51','19'],
['52','34'],
['53','19'],
['54','27'],
['56','27'],
['58','10'],
['59','26'],
['60','54'],
['62','54'],
['64','17'],
['68','27'],
['74','43'],
['75','10'],
['76','32'],
['77','47'],
['78','31'],
['80','24'],
['84','20'],
['85','35'],
['86','33'],
['88','25'],
['89','26'],
['91','35'],
['93','25'],
['94','18'],
['95','24'],
['98','34'],
['100','23'],
['101','36'],
['102','18'],
['103','21'],
['105','16'],
['106','26'],
['107','29'],
['109','8'],
['111','16'],
['112','19'],
['113','33'],
['114','20'],
['115','18'],
['116','21'],
['117','14'],
['126','22'],
['127','26'],
['130','24'],
['131','10'],
['133','29'],
['134','26'],
['135','22'],
['136','16'],
['137','14'],
['139','23'],
['140','17'],
['141','18'],
['142','19'],
['143','15'],
['144','25'],
['145','19'],
['146','23'],
['147','18'],
['148','50'],
['150','47'],
['151','13'],
['152','37'],
['153','24'],
['156','22'],
['157','21'],
['158','40'],
['159','34'],
['160','12'],
['161','22'],
['165','18'],
['168','24'],
['169','23'],
['171','20'],
['172','22'],
['173','25'],
['175','30'],
['176','24'],
['177','15'],
['178','25'],
['179','0'],
['181','28'],
['182','21'],
['183','17'],
['184','22'],
['185','40'],
['187','24'],
['188','22'],
['189','21'],
['190','8'],
['191','18'],
['192','23'],
['193','33'],
['194','30'],
['195','32'],
['196','33'],
['197','31'],
['198','34'],
['199','34'],
['200','31'],
['201','31'],
['203','20'],
['204','34'],
['205','32'],
['206','19'],
['210','24'],
['211','32'],
['212','29'],
['213','19'],
['214','20'],
['215','19'],
['216','21'],
['217','24'],
['218','27'],
['219','22'],
['220','20'],
['221','17'],
['222','18'],
['223','34'],
['224','35'],
['229','19'],
['230','22'],
['231','21'],
['232','23'],
['234','27'],
['235','22'],
['236','12'],
['237','17'],
['238','16'],
['239','19'],
['240','33'],
['241','13'],
['242','24'],
['243','25'],
['244','19'],
['245','19'],
['246','17'],
['247','23'],
['248','22'],
['250','12'],
['252','10'],
['253','13'],
['254','17'],
['256','23'],
['257','16'],
['258','20'],
['259','24'],
['260','36'],
['263','15'],
['264','19'],
['266','24'],
['267','14'],
['270','17'],
['271','23'],
['272','14'],
['274','21'],
['277','26'],
['279','18'],
['280','27'],
['281','26'],
['282','19'],
['283','23'],
['284','19'],
['288','49'],
['289','37'],
['290','31'],
['291','50'],
['296','17'],
['297','29'],
['299','17'],
['301','32'],
['302','34'],
['304','17'],
['305','32'],
['306','23'],
['307','34'],
['309','27'],
['314','20'],
['316','39'],
['317','48'],
['318','34'],
['319','46'],
['326','16'],
['329','0'],
['330','17'],
['334','15'],
['338','4'],
['339','14'],
['341','23'],
['346','31'],
['347','27'],
['348','39'],
['349','20'],
['350','18'],
['351','16'],
['352','20'],
['353','20'],
['354','18'],
['355','29'],
['356','22'],
['360','18'],
['362','0'],
['363','27'],
['367','25'],
['368','15'],
['369','23'],
['370','31'],
['371','43'],
['373','13'],
['374','30'],
['375','43'],
['376','27'],
['377','44'],
['379','35'],
['380','23'],
['382','41'],
['383','31'],
['384','28'],
['385','23'],
['386','19'],
['387','22'],
['388','30'],
['389','31'],
['390','3'],
['391','38'],
['393','7'],
['394','34'],
['396','31'],
['397','31'],
['398','24'],
['399','39'],
['400','31'],
['401','31'],
['402','27'],
['403','12'],
['405','7'],
['406','23'],
['408','24'],
['409','35'],
['410','32'],
['411','31'],
['412','33'],
['415','0'],
['416','25'],
['417','17'],
['418','14'],
['420','9'],
['421','16'],
['422','24'],
['423','49'],
['424','31'],
['426','31'],
['427','25'],
['428','33'],
['429','23'],
['430','31'],
['431','29'],
['433','27'],
['434','14'],
['435','22'],
['436','48'],
['437','30'],
['438','17'],
['439','12'],
['442','18'],
['443','32'],
['444','26'],
['445','14'],
['446','17'],
['447','13'],
['450','20'],
['451','25'],
['452','24'],
['454','14'],
['455','19'],
['456','23'],
['457','15'],
['458','20'],
['459','23'],
['460','21'],
['461','30'],
['462','15'],
['463','26'],
['464','16'],
['465','22'],
['466','20'],
['467','28'],
['468','22'],
['469','27'],
['470','15'],
['476','8'],
['478','7'],
['479','14'],
['481','14'],
['482','8'],
['483','17'],
['484','16'],
['485','10'],
['487','10'],
['488','17'],
['492','12'],
['493','18'],
['496','22'],
['497','14'],
['498','19'],
['500','17'],
['501','13'],
['503','9'],
['504','16'],
['505','19'],
['506','19'],
['507','25'],
['508','27'],
['510','15'],
['512','12'],
['514','8'],
['515','18'],
['517','20'],
['518','14'],
['519','19'],
['520','16'],
['522','15'],
['523','18'],
['525','20'],
['526','21'],
['527','21'],
['528','21'],
['529','26'],
['531','21'],
['533','4'],
['535','16'],
['536','0'],
['537','16'],
['538','16'],
['539','19'],
['540','24'],
['541','17'],
['542','12'],
['543','16'],
['545','16'],
['546','15'],
['547','11'],
['549','8'],
['550','13'],
['551','26'],
['552','35'],
['553','20'],
['554','17'],
['556','0'],
['557','13'],
['558','14'],
['559','13'],
['561','13'],
['563','18'],
['564','19'],
['566','10'],
['567','23'],
['568','8'],
['570','49'],
['571','20'],
['572','36'],
['573','27'],
['574','0'],
['575','24'],
['576','13'],
['577','51'],
['578','0'],
['579','16'],
['582','13'],
['583','16'],
['584','17'],
['585','15'],
['586','19'],
['589','13'],
['590','20'],
['591','18'],
['593','21'],
['594','28'],
['595','35'],
['596','20'],
['597','9'],
['598','5'],
['599','12'],
['600','21'],
['601','16'],
['602','7'],
['604','22'],
['605','44'],
['607','40'],
['608','27'],
['609','16'],
['610','17'],
['612','15'],
['613','14'],
['614','39'],
['615','13'],
['618','7'],
['620','13'],
['621','13'],
['623','27'],
['624','13'],
['625','13'],
['628','16'],
['629','15'],
['630','28'],
['631','10'],
['633','18'],
['634','12'],
['636','14'],
['638','35'],
['639','6'],
['640','14'],
['641','14'],
['642','14'],
['643','28'],
['644','29'],
['645','21'],
['649','15'],
['650','21'],
['651','22'],
['652','20'],
['653','24'],
['654','19'],
['655','17'],
['656','15'],
['657','14'],
['659','11'],
['660','12'],
['663','29'],
['664','14'],
['666','6'],
['667','30'],
['669','7'],
['670','9'],
['671','29'],
['672','19'],
['676','19'],
['679','23'],
['680','16'],
['681','19'],
['682','16'],
['683','35'],
['684','17'],
['685','29'],
['687','35'],
['688','21'],
['689','22'],
['691','20'],
['692','19'],
['693','34'],
['694','26'],
['695','21'],
['697','25'],
['698','20'],
['700','24'],
['701','24'],
['702','25'],
['703','24'],
['704','18'],
['706','20'],
['707','15'],
['708','26'],
['711','9'],
['712','30'],
['713','28'],
['714','49'],
['716','23'],
['717','21'],
['718','33'],
['719','22'],
['720','22'],
['722','19'],
['723','47'],
['725','16'],
['726','12'],
['727','23'],
['728','18'],
['730','36'],
['731','17'],
['732','18'],
['733','31'],
['735','31'],
['737','17'],
['738','15'],
['739','18'],
['741','28'],
['742','28'],
['743','26'],
['744','24'],
['745','0'],
['746','25'],
['747','22'],
['748','24'],
['753','26'],
['755','35'],
['756','26'],
['757','36'],
['758','25'],
['759','23'],
['760','23'],
['761','13'],
['762','18'],
['763','22'],
['764','29'],
['765','20'],
['766','25'],
['767','20'],
['769','18'],
['770','21'],
['773','14'],
['774','21'],
['781','38'],
['783','29'],
['784','24'],
['785','31'],
['786','33'],
['790','30'],
['791','13'],
['792','19'],
['793','20'],
['794','20'],
['796','15'],
['797','23'],
['798','20'],
['799','16'],
['801','36'],
['802','40'],
['803','29'],
['805','33'],
['809','27'],
['810','23'],
['811','28'],
['812','22'],
['813','25'],
['815','4'],
['816','19'],
['817','30'],
['818','34'],
['819','20'],
['820','19'],
['821','20'],
['822','14'],
['823','20'],
['824','23'],
['827','14'],
['829','31'],
['830','14'],
['831','32'],
['832','38'],
['834','17'],
['835','32'],
['841','21'],
['845','40'],
['847','14'],
['848','13'],
['849','15'],
['850','10'],
['851','13'],
['852','14'],
['854','23'],
['855','22'],
['857','18'],
['858','16'],
['859','25'],
['860','15'],
['862','15'],
['863','13'],
['864','25'],
['865','22'],
['867','19'],
['868','19'],
['869','20'],
['870','18'],
['872','19'],
['873','7'],
['875','19'],
['876','19'],
['877','13'],
['878','19'],
['879','25'],
['880','26'],
['882','33'],
['883','21'],
['884','36'],
['888','27'],
['889','14'],
['891','22'],
['893','13'],
['894','14'],
['895','21'],
['898','6'],
['900','21'],
['901','31'],
['902','21'],
['903','15'],
['904','11'],
['913','21'],
['915','13'],
['916','14'],
['917','32'],
['918','32'],
['922','28'],
['923','19'],
['924','18'],
['926','26'],
['930','13'],
['931','10'],
['933','19'],
['934','27'],
['935','6'],
['937','4'],
['938','13'],
['940','27'],
['941','16'],
['945','16'],
['946','14'],
['948','0'],
['949','22'],
['952','17'],
['953','21'],
['954','25'],
['955','21'],
['956','21'],
['957','6'],
['958','8'],
['959','24'],
['960','28'],
['961','45'],
['962','23'],
['963','19'],
['964','13'],
['965','14'],
['966','40'],
['967','9'],
['968','22'],
['969','18'],
['970','24'],
['971','18'],
['973','37'],
['974','52'],
['976','17'],
['977','24'],
['978','14'],
['979','28'],
['980','32'],
['982','23'],
['983','24'],
['985','30'],
['986','13'],
['989','19'],
['990','23'],
['992','21'],
['993','22'],
['995','31'],
['996','27'],
['997','24'],
['999','25'],
['1000','27'],
['1002','10'],
['1003','19'],
['1004','29'],
['1005','6'],
['1006','10'],

          ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Distribution of Bus Speeds on Beer Sheva PT Segments 7-10AM',
                    hAxis: {title: 'Bus Speeds (kph)',
                           titleTextStyle: {
                                italic: false
            }},             
          vAxis: {title: 'PT Segments Count',
                 titleTextStyle: {
                                italic: false
            }},    
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          histogram: { bucketSize: 5 },
           colors:['red','yellow']


        };



        var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On another part of my screen I have a map showing the data points separately.
I want to filter the map using the IDs of each data point of a selected bar. That is, if the user selects a bar in the histogram, I need to get all the IDs of data points in that bar.

I've been fishing around the web, but mostly found solutions for getting a specific item using chart.getSelection().

I tried to also get the column range, but got unclear results of min=0 and max=999.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a Histogram, `getSelection()` only returns the index of the selected bar,
it does not return the row indexes from the data table,
as it does with other charts.

in this case, we need to use --> `getChartLayoutInterface()`
the layout interface is an object we can use to find the position of various chart elements.

first, we use `getSelection()` to determine which bar, and / or series, is selected.
`getSelection()` will return something similar to --> `[{"row":3,"column":1}]`

where `row` is the selected bar, and `column` is the data table column,
and `column - 1` is the series index.

next, we use the layout interface method --> `getBoundingBox(id)`
where `id` is the id of the chart element, for a bar it takes the following format.
`bar#series#row` -- `bar#0#3`
as such, `getBoundingBox('bar#0#3')` will give us the dimensions of the fourth bar.
something like --> `{"left":381,"top":60.5,"width":89,"height":103}`

then we can use layout interface method --> `getHAxisValue(position)`
this will return the value on the x-axis for the given position

by providing the left and right coordinates of the bar,
we can determine the min and max values of the range

with the range, we can then filter the data table to determine which rows make up the bar.

here is the snippet...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    // get position of selected bar
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var barBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('bar#' + (selection[0].column - 1) + '#' + selection[0].row);

    // get rows for selected bar
    var rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: selection[0].column,
      minValue: chartLayout.getHAxisValue(barBounds.left),
      maxValue: chartLayout.getHAxisValue(barBounds.left + barBounds.width)
    }]);

    // create data view for selected rows
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setRows(rows);

    // get ids of selected bar
    var ids = view.getDistinctValues(0);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

the number of items in the above snippet was off.
instead of using `minValue` & `maxValue`,
we need to use the `test` function.

where the value of each row is...

```
>= min value of the range
<  max value of the range
```

the above was `>=` & `<=`

and we may also need to use `Math.ceil` on the min value,
and `Math.floor` on the max value.

the following snippet appears to sync with the chart...

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    // get position of selected bar
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var barBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('bar#' + (selection[0].column - 1) + '#' + selection[0].row);

    // get rows for selected bar
    var rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: selection[0].column,
      test: function (value) {
        return ((value >= Math.ceil(chartLayout.getHAxisValue(barBounds.left))) &&
                (value < Math.floor(chartLayout.getHAxisValue(barBounds.left + barBounds.width))));
      }
    }]);

    // create data view for selected rows
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setRows(rows);

    // get ids of selected bar
    var ids = view.getDistinctValues(0);
    console.log(ids.length);
  }
});
```

see following working example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['pt_network_seg_id','speed'],
    ['9',32],
    ['10',22],
    ['13',23],
    ['14',18],
    ['15',34],
    ['17',22],
    ['18',30],
    ['19',20],
    ['20',33],
    ['21',26],
    ['22',33],
    ['23',21],
    ['24',19],
    ['25',41],
    ['26',23],
    ['27',16],
    ['28',39],
    ['29',15],
    ['30',25],
    ['31',26],
    ['32',29],
    ['40',31],
    ['41',9],
    ['42',27],
    ['44',25],
    ['45',10],
    ['46',25],
    ['47',24],
    ['48',20],
    ['49',20],
    ['50',25],
    ['51',19],
    ['52',34],
    ['53',19],
    ['54',27],
    ['56',27],
    ['58',10],
    ['59',26],
    ['60',54],
    ['62',54],
    ['64',17],
    ['68',27],
    ['74',43],
    ['75',10],
    ['76',32],
    ['77',47],
    ['78',31],
    ['80',24],
    ['84',20],
    ['85',35],
    ['86',33],
    ['88',25],
    ['89',26],
    ['91',35],
    ['93',25],
    ['94',18],
    ['95',24],
    ['98',34],
    ['100',23],
    ['101',36],
    ['102',18],
    ['103',21],
    ['105',16],
    ['106',26],
    ['107',29],
    ['109',8],
    ['111',16],
    ['112',19],
    ['113',33],
    ['114',20],
    ['115',18],
    ['116',21],
    ['117',14],
    ['126',22],
    ['127',26],
    ['130',24],
    ['131',10],
    ['133',29],
    ['134',26],
    ['135',22],
    ['136',16],
    ['137',14],
    ['139',23],
    ['140',17],
    ['141',18],
    ['142',19],
    ['143',15],
    ['144',25],
    ['145',19],
    ['146',23],
    ['147',18],
    ['148',50],
    ['150',47],
    ['151',13],
    ['152',37],
    ['153',24],
    ['156',22],
    ['157',21],
    ['158',40],
    ['159',34],
    ['160',12],
    ['161',22],
    ['165',18],
    ['168',24],
    ['169',23],
    ['171',20],
    ['172',22],
    ['173',25],
    ['175',30],
    ['176',24],
    ['177',15],
    ['178',25],
    ['179',0],
    ['181',28],
    ['182',21],
    ['183',17],
    ['184',22],
    ['185',40],
    ['187',24],
    ['188',22],
    ['189',21],
    ['190',8],
    ['191',18],
    ['192',23],
    ['193',33],
    ['194',30],
    ['195',32],
    ['196',33],
    ['197',31],
    ['198',34],
    ['199',34],
    ['200',31],
    ['201',31],
    ['203',20],
    ['204',34],
    ['205',32],
    ['206',19],
    ['210',24],
    ['211',32],
    ['212',29],
    ['213',19],
    ['214',20],
    ['215',19],
    ['216',21],
    ['217',24],
    ['218',27],
    ['219',22],
    ['220',20],
    ['221',17],
    ['222',18],
    ['223',34],
    ['224',35],
    ['229',19],
    ['230',22],
    ['231',21],
    ['232',23],
    ['234',27],
    ['235',22],
    ['236',12],
    ['237',17],
    ['238',16],
    ['239',19],
    ['240',33],
    ['241',13],
    ['242',24],
    ['243',25],
    ['244',19],
    ['245',19],
    ['246',17],
    ['247',23],
    ['248',22],
    ['250',12],
    ['252',10],
    ['253',13],
    ['254',17],
    ['256',23],
    ['257',16],
    ['258',20],
    ['259',24],
    ['260',36],
    ['263',15],
    ['264',19],
    ['266',24],
    ['267',14],
    ['270',17],
    ['271',23],
    ['272',14],
    ['274',21],
    ['277',26],
    ['279',18],
    ['280',27],
    ['281',26],
    ['282',19],
    ['283',23],
    ['284',19],
    ['288',49],
    ['289',37],
    ['290',31],
    ['291',50],
    ['296',17],
    ['297',29],
    ['299',17],
    ['301',32],
    ['302',34],
    ['304',17],
    ['305',32],
    ['306',23],
    ['307',34],
    ['309',27],
    ['314',20],
    ['316',39],
    ['317',48],
    ['318',34],
    ['319',46],
    ['326',16],
    ['329',0],
    ['330',17],
    ['334',15],
    ['338',4],
    ['339',14],
    ['341',23],
    ['346',31],
    ['347',27],
    ['348',39],
    ['349',20],
    ['350',18],
    ['351',16],
    ['352',20],
    ['353',20],
    ['354',18],
    ['355',29],
    ['356',22],
    ['360',18],
    ['362',0],
    ['363',27],
    ['367',25],
    ['368',15],
    ['369',23],
    ['370',31],
    ['371',43],
    ['373',13],
    ['374',30],
    ['375',43],
    ['376',27],
    ['377',44],
    ['379',35],
    ['380',23],
    ['382',41],
    ['383',31],
    ['384',28],
    ['385',23],
    ['386',19],
    ['387',22],
    ['388',30],
    ['389',31],
    ['390',3],
    ['391',38],
    ['393',7],
    ['394',34],
    ['396',31],
    ['397',31],
    ['398',24],
    ['399',39],
    ['400',31],
    ['401',31],
    ['402',27],
    ['403',12],
    ['405',7],
    ['406',23],
    ['408',24],
    ['409',35],
    ['410',32],
    ['411',31],
    ['412',33],
    ['415',0],
    ['416',25],
    ['417',17],
    ['418',14],
    ['420',9],
    ['421',16],
    ['422',24],
    ['423',49],
    ['424',31],
    ['426',31],
    ['427',25],
    ['428',33],
    ['429',23],
    ['430',31],
    ['431',29],
    ['433',27],
    ['434',14],
    ['435',22],
    ['436',48],
    ['437',30],
    ['438',17],
    ['439',12],
    ['442',18],
    ['443',32],
    ['444',26],
    ['445',14],
    ['446',17],
    ['447',13],
    ['450',20],
    ['451',25],
    ['452',24],
    ['454',14],
    ['455',19],
    ['456',23],
    ['457',15],
    ['458',20],
    ['459',23],
    ['460',21],
    ['461',30],
    ['462',15],
    ['463',26],
    ['464',16],
    ['465',22],
    ['466',20],
    ['467',28],
    ['468',22],
    ['469',27],
    ['470',15],
    ['476',8],
    ['478',7],
    ['479',14],
    ['481',14],
    ['482',8],
    ['483',17],
    ['484',16],
    ['485',10],
    ['487',10],
    ['488',17],
    ['492',12],
    ['493',18],
    ['496',22],
    ['497',14],
    ['498',19],
    ['500',17],
    ['501',13],
    ['503',9],
    ['504',16],
    ['505',19],
    ['506',19],
    ['507',25],
    ['508',27],
    ['510',15],
    ['512',12],
    ['514',8],
    ['515',18],
    ['517',20],
    ['518',14],
    ['519',19],
    ['520',16],
    ['522',15],
    ['523',18],
    ['525',20],
    ['526',21],
    ['527',21],
    ['528',21],
    ['529',26],
    ['531',21],
    ['533',4],
    ['535',16],
    ['536',0],
    ['537',16],
    ['538',16],
    ['539',19],
    ['540',24],
    ['541',17],
    ['542',12],
    ['543',16],
    ['545',16],
    ['546',15],
    ['547',11],
    ['549',8],
    ['550',13],
    ['551',26],
    ['552',35],
    ['553',20],
    ['554',17],
    ['556',0],
    ['557',13],
    ['558',14],
    ['559',13],
    ['561',13],
    ['563',18],
    ['564',19],
    ['566',10],
    ['567',23],
    ['568',8],
    ['570',49],
    ['571',20],
    ['572',36],
    ['573',27],
    ['574',0],
    ['575',24],
    ['576',13],
    ['577',51],
    ['578',0],
    ['579',16],
    ['582',13],
    ['583',16],
    ['584',17],
    ['585',15],
    ['586',19],
    ['589',13],
    ['590',20],
    ['591',18],
    ['593',21],
    ['594',28],
    ['595',35],
    ['596',20],
    ['597',9],
    ['598',5],
    ['599',12],
    ['600',21],
    ['601',16],
    ['602',7],
    ['604',22],
    ['605',44],
    ['607',40],
    ['608',27],
    ['609',16],
    ['610',17],
    ['612',15],
    ['613',14],
    ['614',39],
    ['615',13],
    ['618',7],
    ['620',13],
    ['621',13],
    ['623',27],
    ['624',13],
    ['625',13],
    ['628',16],
    ['629',15],
    ['630',28],
    ['631',10],
    ['633',18],
    ['634',12],
    ['636',14],
    ['638',35],
    ['639',6],
    ['640',14],
    ['641',14],
    ['642',14],
    ['643',28],
    ['644',29],
    ['645',21],
    ['649',15],
    ['650',21],
    ['651',22],
    ['652',20],
    ['653',24],
    ['654',19],
    ['655',17],
    ['656',15],
    ['657',14],
    ['659',11],
    ['660',12],
    ['663',29],
    ['664',14],
    ['666',6],
    ['667',30],
    ['669',7],
    ['670',9],
    ['671',29],
    ['672',19],
    ['676',19],
    ['679',23],
    ['680',16],
    ['681',19],
    ['682',16],
    ['683',35],
    ['684',17],
    ['685',29],
    ['687',35],
    ['688',21],
    ['689',22],
    ['691',20],
    ['692',19],
    ['693',34],
    ['694',26],
    ['695',21],
    ['697',25],
    ['698',20],
    ['700',24],
    ['701',24],
    ['702',25],
    ['703',24],
    ['704',18],
    ['706',20],
    ['707',15],
    ['708',26],
    ['711',9],
    ['712',30],
    ['713',28],
    ['714',49],
    ['716',23],
    ['717',21],
    ['718',33],
    ['719',22],
    ['720',22],
    ['722',19],
    ['723',47],
    ['725',16],
    ['726',12],
    ['727',23],
    ['728',18],
    ['730',36],
    ['731',17],
    ['732',18],
    ['733',31],
    ['735',31],
    ['737',17],
    ['738',15],
    ['739',18],
    ['741',28],
    ['742',28],
    ['743',26],
    ['744',24],
    ['745',0],
    ['746',25],
    ['747',22],
    ['748',24],
    ['753',26],
    ['755',35],
    ['756',26],
    ['757',36],
    ['758',25],
    ['759',23],
    ['760',23],
    ['761',13],
    ['762',18],
    ['763',22],
    ['764',29],
    ['765',20],
    ['766',25],
    ['767',20],
    ['769',18],
    ['770',21],
    ['773',14],
    ['774',21],
    ['781',38],
    ['783',29],
    ['784',24],
    ['785',31],
    ['786',33],
    ['790',30],
    ['791',13],
    ['792',19],
    ['793',20],
    ['794',20],
    ['796',15],
    ['797',23],
    ['798',20],
    ['799',16],
    ['801',36],
    ['802',40],
    ['803',29],
    ['805',33],
    ['809',27],
    ['810',23],
    ['811',28],
    ['812',22],
    ['813',25],
    ['815',4],
    ['816',19],
    ['817',30],
    ['818',34],
    ['819',20],
    ['820',19],
    ['821',20],
    ['822',14],
    ['823',20],
    ['824',23],
    ['827',14],
    ['829',31],
    ['830',14],
    ['831',32],
    ['832',38],
    ['834',17],
    ['835',32],
    ['841',21],
    ['845',40],
    ['847',14],
    ['848',13],
    ['849',15],
    ['850',10],
    ['851',13],
    ['852',14],
    ['854',23],
    ['855',22],
    ['857',18],
    ['858',16],
    ['859',25],
    ['860',15],
    ['862',15],
    ['863',13],
    ['864',25],
    ['865',22],
    ['867',19],
    ['868',19],
    ['869',20],
    ['870',18],
    ['872',19],
    ['873',7],
    ['875',19],
    ['876',19],
    ['877',13],
    ['878',19],
    ['879',25],
    ['880',26],
    ['882',33],
    ['883',21],
    ['884',36],
    ['888',27],
    ['889',14],
    ['891',22],
    ['893',13],
    ['894',14],
    ['895',21],
    ['898',6],
    ['900',21],
    ['901',31],
    ['902',21],
    ['903',15],
    ['904',11],
    ['913',21],
    ['915',13],
    ['916',14],
    ['917',32],
    ['918',32],
    ['922',28],
    ['923',19],
    ['924',18],
    ['926',26],
    ['930',13],
    ['931',10],
    ['933',19],
    ['934',27],
    ['935',6],
    ['937',4],
    ['938',13],
    ['940',27],
    ['941',16],
    ['945',16],
    ['946',14],
    ['948',0],
    ['949',22],
    ['952',17],
    ['953',21],
    ['954',25],
    ['955',21],
    ['956',21],
    ['957',6],
    ['958',8],
    ['959',24],
    ['960',28],
    ['961',45],
    ['962',23],
    ['963',19],
    ['964',13],
    ['965',14],
    ['966',40],
    ['967',9],
    ['968',22],
    ['969',18],
    ['970',24],
    ['971',18],
    ['973',37],
    ['974',52],
    ['976',17],
    ['977',24],
    ['978',14],
    ['979',28],
    ['980',32],
    ['982',23],
    ['983',24],
    ['985',30],
    ['986',13],
    ['989',19],
    ['990',23],
    ['992',21],
    ['993',22],
    ['995',31],
    ['996',27],
    ['997',24],
    ['999',25],
    ['1000',27],
    ['1002',10],
    ['1003',19],
    ['1004',29],
    ['1005',6],
    ['1006',10]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Distribution of Bus Speeds on Beer Sheva PT Segments 7-10AM',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Bus Speeds (kph)',
      titleTextStyle: {
        italic: false
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'PT Segments Count',
      titleTextStyle: {
        italic: false
      }
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    histogram: {
      bucketSize: 5
    },
    colors:['red', 'yellow']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      // get position of selected bar
      var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
      var barBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('bar#' + (selection[0].column - 1) + '#' + selection[0].row);

      // get rows for selected bar
      var rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: selection[0].column,
        test: function (value) {
          return ((value >= Math.ceil(chartLayout.getHAxisValue(barBounds.left))) && (value < Math.floor(chartLayout.getHAxisValue(barBounds.left + barBounds.width))));
        }
      }]);

      // create data view for selected rows
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setRows(rows);

      // get ids of selected bar
      var ids = view.getDistinctValues(0);
      console.log(ids.length);
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, it seems that there's a mismatch. If you click on the 3rd bar it outputs 115 elements, but the hover shows 91 elements. Any idea why?

Comment: This saved me so much time. I'm glad they made is so simple ;)